# SSH Connection - Interact with ongoing process

Tags: ssh, scripting, terminal

If i open a Terminal window on my desktop and start a job on it and go to work in the morning. Is there a way to connect to the desktop with SSH and interact with the ongoing process in the Terminal window? So I can get the result in the SSH session and continue the job.

I can see the terminal window from ps list.

```
2012 ?        00:02:30 gnome-terminal-
```

EDIT: What about socket's? If my bash script open's a unecrypted socket from local port X to remote port Y on remote address A, is there someway to see the traffic and interact with it?

Answer (score 4):

The venerable [Gnu Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) can do what you want, but it can't attach to an already running gnome-terminal. You'll need to start `screen` at work if you want to pick it up later at home.

See [Session Management](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Session-Management) specifically.

Answer (score 1):

On your home computer, before starting the job, launch =screen=:

```
screen
```

Then, from work or where ever, ssh into your home machine. Once in a shell, connect to the screen instance running there:

```
screen -raAd
```

That's -r[eattach] -a[ll capabilities] -A[dapt the size of the screen] -d[etach screen if running elsewhere]

Do whatever you want to do in that screen instance, and when finished, detach from it using `ctrl-a` and then `d`.

Once detached, exit the ssh session with `exit` as usual.